# Nested case query Db2

Tags: db2

I am trying to create a nested case statement in DB2. It's throwing me an error.

```
select tmp.claim_number,
       SUM(tmp.LUMP_SUM_E) as LUMP_SUM_E
  from (
select c.claim_number,
       p.amount,
       p.effective_gross_amt,
       --p.lump_sum_e,
       p.released,
       p.to,
       p.payment_option,
       p.sub_benefit_type,
       p.PAYMENT_FIELD,
       CASE WHEN ((EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.to) < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.released)) 
       THEN
          CASE WHEN (p.to <= '2020-07-01' and p.amount > 0)
          THEN amount ELSE 0 
          END  
       END AS lump_sum_e   
from CLAIMS.claim c inner join claims.payment p on c.id = p.claim_id and c.claim_Number IN (75248)
AND (
      (p.RELEASED >= '2020-07-01' AND p.RELEASED <= '2021-06-30') 
   OR 
      (p.ATO_RELEASE_DATE >= '2020-07-01' AND p.ATO_RELEASE_DATE <= '2021-06-30')
    )
  ) tmp
GROUP by tmp.claim_number;
```

it's throwing

```
1) [Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "THEN" was found following "FROM p.released))  
".  Expected tokens may include:  ")".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.22.29
2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-104", SQLSTATE "42601" and message tokens "THEN|FROM p.released))  
|)".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.22.29
```

Any idea how to write a nested case statement in Db2 please?.

Regards,
R

Comment: Have you used additional brackets / parenthesis (`(` and `)`) around the inner CASE? Based on syntax it is possible. Also, there seems to be an issue with the parenthesis around your first WHEN

Comment: Great. I added my comment as answer, so that this question can be marked answered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your query syntax.

```
select tmp.claim_number,
       SUM(tmp.LUMP_SUM_E) as LUMP_SUM_E
  from (select c.claim_number,
               p.amount,
               p.effective_gross_amt,
               --p.lump_sum_e,
               p.released,
               p.to,
               p.payment_option,
               p.sub_benefit_type,
               p.PAYMENT_FIELD,
               CASE WHEN (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.to) < EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.released)) 
                         THEN
                             CASE WHEN (p.to <= '2020-07-01' and p.amount > 0)
                                       THEN amount ELSE 0 
                             END  
               END AS lump_sum_e   
          from CLAIMS.claim c 
         inner join claims.payment p on c.id = p.claim_id 
                                    and c.claim_Number IN (75248)
                                    AND (
                                         (p.RELEASED >= '2020-07-01'
                                          AND p.RELEASED <= '2021-06-30') 
                                         OR 
                                         (p.ATO_RELEASE_DATE >= '2020-07-01'
                                          AND p.ATO_RELEASE_DATE <= '2021-06-30')
                                        )
      ) tmp
GROUP by tmp.claim_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using explicit parenthesis around the inner CASE expression. Also make sure that the `(` and `)` are in sync. Based on the syntax for the [CASE statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-case) it should work.